# Quadratic Forms and their Matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

> 1) How do you manage to transform a matrix from quadratic to canonical form?

For instance, assume a linear transformation such that: 
$$Q(x,y,z)=x^2+2xz+z^2;$$

As far as I can see, in the canonical form this would just be $a^2+b^2$, $a=x+z$ and $b=y$, but the correct answer is something entirely different according to my book.

> 2) Assume for instance the linear transformation $Q(x,y,z)=x^2+xy+xz+yz$. How would you find its quadratic matrix $Q$, its symmetric part $B$ (I assume it is the sum of the quadratic and the quadratic transposed divided by $2$, but I'm not entirely sure), a diagonal quadratic form $G$ and the diagonalizing matrix $S$?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that there isn't unicity of decomposition.

We have for your example
\begin{align}Q(x,y,z)&=x^2+xy+xz+yz=x^2+x(y+z)+yz\\&=\left(x+\frac{1}{2}(y+z)\right)^2-\frac{1}{4}(y+z)^2+yz\\&=\left(x+\frac{1}{2}(y+z)\right)^2-\frac{1}{4}y^2-\frac{1}{4}z^2+\frac{1}{2}yz\\&=\left(x+\frac{1}{2}(y+z)\right)^2-\frac{1}{4}(y-z)^2\end{align}

The matrix of the quadratic form is
$$A=\left(\begin{matrix}1&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2}&0&\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&0\end{matrix}\right)$$
and we have
$$Q(x,y,z)=(x,y,z)A \left(\begin{matrix}x\\
y\\
z\end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: Ok, I believe I understood that one. Could you also help me with 2) please?

Comment: @Curious I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks once again! Following the equation it all made sense. Could you finally also show me, if it isn't too much trouble, how to discover G and S? (I've managed B)

Comment: Diagonalize $B$  in an orthonormal basis containing eigenvectors of $B$ and hence you have $B=P G P^T$ where $P$ is the matrix which its columns are the eigenvectors of the basis.